# computers mathematical finding value in triangle

Tags: math, graphics, computer-science

3D triangle with vertices (0,0,0), (1,1,1), (1,-1,2). What is the z value of the point in the triangle with x=3, y=1? how to find the Z value?

Comment: Do you mean the plane defined by those three points? There is no point in or on that triangle with x=3, y=1. Those three points do however define a plane, and there is a point on the plane with those x and y coordinates. The z coordinate of that point is 4.

Comment: I need to know how to find the z value for this or other examples

Comment: In one of the answers, you continue to ask about the triangle even though it should be obvious that there is no point on or in the triangle with x=3 and y=1. Just look at the x values. One of the legs connects (0,0,0) and (1,1,1). The x coordinates on this leg will be between 0 and 1. Another leg connects (0,0,0) and (1,-1,2). Once again, the x coordinates are between 0 and 1. The third leg connects (1,1,1) and (1,-1,2). Here the x coordinates are identically one. The only points on the triangle have x coordinates between 0 and 1, and this is also true for points in the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Just use wolframalpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plane+through+%280%2C0%2C0%29%2C+%281%2C1%2C1%29%2C+and+%281%2C-1%2C2%29

The plane is 
**-3x + y + 2z = 0**,
Therefore, z = 4.

Comment: Here's an article on wikipedia regarding plane construction http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Describing_a_plane_through_three_points

Comment: What's the equation and the methodes to find z value

Answer (score 0):

Any point (x,y,z) in the plane defined by the three points satisfies the equation

```
       | 0  1  1  x |
       | 0  1 -1  y |
0 = det| 0  1  2  z |
       | 1  1  1  1 |
```

where the columns are the given points in the first three coordinates and an additional fourth coordinate 1, making it homogeneous coordinates resp. marking the vectors as points of an affine point space.

This can be reduced by the usual determinant operations, here dominantly column operations, subtracting the first column from all other and the second from the third
and then the third from the second

```
       | 0  1  0  x |
       | 0  3 -2  y |
0 = det| 0  0  1  z |
       | 1  0  0  0 |
```

and then developing in the last column gives

```
0 = x*(3*1-(-2)*0)-y*(1*1-0*0)+z*(1*(-2)-0*3)
  = 3*x-y-2*z
```

Using the provided x and y coordinates gives the determinant (using the same transformations as before)

```
       | 0  1  0  3 |      | 0  1  0  0 ||
       | 0  3 -2  1 |      | 0  3 -2 -8 |
0 = det| 0  0  1  z | = det| 0  0  1  z |
       | 1  0  0  0 |      | 1  0  0  0 |

       | 0  1  0  0   | 
       | 0  3 -2  0   | 
  = det| 0  0  1  z-4 | 
       | 1  0  0  0   |
```

Which will be zero if z=4, so the last column is zero.

---

As a general computer algorithm, one would compute the determinant twice for concrete values of z, so that the matrix has no variables, only numbers as components; once for z=0 giving D0 and then for z=1 giving the value D1. Then the equation to solve is

```
D0+D1*z=0  or  z=-D0/D1
```

Comment: I can't be clear>> I need how do we find the z value in 3d triangle "the method" for any example!thanx

Comment: Compute the determinants D0 and D1 and then z=-D0/D1. But this does not tell you if the point is inside the triangle. Convert to barycentric coordinates to get easy conditions for that.

Comment: @user3182898 - I've been clear. There is no z value for the point x=3, y=1 because there is no point on or in your triangle with those x and y components. **Are you asking about a plane or a triangle**?

Comment: This is visible from the x coordinates alone. The three given points have 0 and 1 as x coordinates, so any point inside the triangle must have x between 0 and 1. The y coordinate taken alone tells us that any point in the triangle except the corner point (1,1,1) has y smaller than 1, so again (3,1,z) can not be inside the triangle. But these kind of arguments only define a rectangular box around the triangle, they are necessary, but not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In three dimensional space, the equation of a plane is the set of all points *p* that satisfy *(p-a)·n* = 0 where *a* is a known point on the plane, *n* is a vector normal to the plane, and *(p-a)·n* is the vector dot product between *p-a* and the normal vector *n*. In this case, the origin is known to be on the plane, so this simplifies to *p·n* = 0.

All we need to do is find a normal, and that's easy. Use the vector cross product. Given three non-colinear points *a*, *b*, and *c* in three dimensional space, the vector *n* = *(b-a)* × *(c-a)* is normal to the plane defined by *a*, *b*, and *c*. Once again using the fact that one of the three points is the origin in this case, this simplifies to {1,1,1} × {1,-1,2} = {3,-1,-2}.

Thus the plane defined by the points (0,0,0), (1,1,1), (1,-1,2) is given by {*x,y,z*}·{3,-1,-2} = 0, or 3x-y-2z=0.